# Refresh issue in Swing when long tasks are called

Tags: java, swing

I am using JDK 1.6.0.18 for my Swing application. I am experiencing very different problem when i try to run it sometimes it doesn't refresh few windows. Whereas when I run it on JDK 1.6.0. everything works fine.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with JDK 1.6.0.18

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you explain your problem a little more ? what are exactly the problem you're having ? do you get exceptions ?

Comment: Ok. Please find below the scenario
1) Application make hundreds of queries to the server and filled the data model
2)Once the data model is filled. It shows it the JTable and calls refresh

I got no exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.
I got my problem solved. The problem was List which was used by 2 or more threads concurrently
and was not thread safe also. Because of some essential condition we have to keep the refresh of window at the time when that List get filled. So on some machines the count was coming wrong.

Especially on machinbe with higher configuratuions line quad core procesors, 4GB ram etc.

Making the List synchornized removed the issue of REFRESH :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are comparing to (1.5.x?).

In general, refresh problems that are intermittent are ofter
cause by not calling swing-functions from the swing-thread.
(See SwingUtilities.invoke/invokelater)

Comment: I am comparing between 1.6.0 and 1.6.0.18 .
And i checked that all the refresh are made using SwingUtilities.

Comment: Can u please tell whether the refresh problem will still persist if i tried to resize the panel, iff repaint is called from outside the Event dispatch thread.